# How to install LaTeX packages for Tex Live?

Tags: software-installation, latex, texlive

Apparently I am using Tex Live as my LaTeX distribution:

```
martin@martin-XPS-8300:~$ pdflatex -v

pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian) kpathsea version
6.1.0 Copyright 2012 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX). 
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and the Lesser GNU
General Public License. For more information about these matters, see
the file named COPYING and the pdfTeX source. Primary author of
pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX). Compiled
with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.49 Compiled with zlib 1.2.7;
using zlib 1.2.7 Compiled with poppler version 0.20.5
```

I would like to install additional packages using [this guide](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages).

They say:

> With TeX Live manually installed, use tlmgr to manage packages
>   individually.

```
tlmgr install <package1> <package2> ... 
tlmgr remove <package1> <package2> ...
```

But when I try:

```
tlmgr install algorithm2e
```

I get:

```
tlmgr: command not found
```

I also do not seem to have a `~/texmf` folder, only a `~/.texmf-var` folder. Is my installation corrupt or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I found that I actually have a

```
/usr/local/share/texmf
```

EDIT2:

The command:

```
apt-cache policy texlive
```

results in:

```
texlive:
  Installed: 2012.20120611-5
  Candidate: 2012.20120611-5
  Version table:
 *** 2012.20120611-5 0
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

folder.

Comment: How did you installed Tex Live?

Comment: I am sorry, but I really do not remember. I think it was through the command line or it was pre-installed. I did not use a package management tool.

Comment: what's the output of `apt-cache policy texlive`?

Comment: If you put the package I linked to in `/usr/local/share/texmf`that should work too I think. Then run `sudo texhash`.

Comment: See [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137)

Comment: @MartinSchröder Thank you! That was it. I put the files into `~/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff` and it works. There is even no need to run `texhash`.

Comment: I recommend this answer [How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system "How do I install an individual package on a Linux system?") where the first answer has great description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you install TeXLive from the ubuntu repositories (Ubuntu software Center). Then tlmgr isn't installed, because all packages should use the system package management system 'apt-get'. Hence you get the error:

```
tlmgr: command not found
```

So you will have to install the package manually:

Download [algorithm2e.sty here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex)

Then, go to the folder `~/texmf` or `~/.texmf` it depends, if it doesn't exist create it:

```
mkdir ~/texmf
```

and copy algorithm2e.sty to it. Then run:

```
sudo texhash
```

put in root password when requested.

unfortunately, the TexLive packages in Ubuntu are not very often updated so some errors might come up.

The alternative is manually installing the entire TexLive distribution and following the guide you posted.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you! I tried both putting it into `/usr/local/share/texmf` as well as creating my own `texmf` folder in the home directory and running `texhash`, but it did not work. But when I include the `algorithm2e.sty` directly into the same folder as the `.tex` file that I am compiling, it works.

Comment: The canonical answer is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files

Comment: Could you try putting it in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` if it works I will update my answer.

Answer (score 9):

TeXLive is divided into *collections*. Every TeXLive package belongs to one (and only one) collection, for example the package `algorithm2e` belongs to the collection `science`. For simplicity, most distributions, including Ubuntu, do not have a package for every individual TeXLive package, but group together all the TeXLive packages in a  given collection and distribute the entire collection as a single package.

In Ubuntu, the TeXLive collection `foo` is distributed as the Ubuntu package `texlive-foo`, so for example the collection `science` is distributed as the Ubuntu package `texlive-science`. Hence, the Ubuntu answer to your question about how to install the TeXLive package `algorithm2e` is that you need to install the Ubuntu package `texlive-science`. (Of course, a side effect is that it will also install all the other packages in the `science` collection.)

The standard way to determine which collection a TeXLive packages belongs to is to use `tlmgr`:

```
$ tlmgr info algorithm2e
package:     algorithm2e
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Floating algorithm environment with algorithmic keywords.
longdesc:    Algorithm2e is an environment for writing algorithms. An algorithm becomes a floating object (like figure, table, etc.). The package provides macros that allow you to create different keywords, and a set of predefined key words is provided; you can change the typography of the keywords. The package allows vertical lines delimiting a block of instructions in an algorithm, and defines different sorts of algorithms such as Procedure or Function; the name of these functions may be reused in the text or in other algorithms.
installed:   Yes
revision:    28749
sizes:       doc: 661k, run: 137k
relocatable: Yes
cat-version: 5.0
cat-date:    2013-01-06 21:16:44 +0100
cat-license: lppl
collection:  collection-science
```

But in Ubuntu, `tlmgr` is not installed. I like to use `apt-file`:

```
$ apt-file search algorithm2e.sty
texlive-science: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithm2e/algorithm2e.sty
```

or you can search for it in the "Search the contents of packages" section of http://packages.ubuntu.com/.

Answer (score 3):

go to ubuntu software center, and install the software TeX Live: Additional fonts.

Comment: This is correct in pointing to the Software Center (for some packages at least) - but the question was about any packages, not just fonts.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I found is, just search for the package in the ubuntu software center. For example I needed the package "braket", I just typed it in the software center, search result showed "TeX Live: LaTeX additional packages" which contains the "braket" package along with a bunch of other packages, I installed it and I am happy now.

Alternatively:

The best way to get the best out of Texlive is to install Telxlive vanilla by following these instructions:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/63118

This will probably solve all problems related to packages and everything else.