# How do I install packages to TeXstudio?

Tags: 16.04, latex

How do I install packages to TeXstudio? I tried compiling a tex file and TeXstudio is not finding placeins.sty, sectsty.sty, etc.

Should I follow [this manual installation guide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Manual_installation), or is there a faster way? Should I use `tlmgr`?

This attempted solution didn't work:

```
$ tlmgr update --all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/sony/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5604.
```

I might have found [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/145667/112712), but I encounter the same error:

```
$ tlmgr info placeins
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/sony/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5604.
```

I am currently reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147090/112712) in response. I am concerned by this output:

```
$ tlmgr init-usertree
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: action init-usertree returned a warning.
```

Why did it just say "there was a warning" without giving me more info?
 ...

Trying to find the first package I need to install to compile my paper, I encounter the following problem:

```
$ tlmgr info placeins
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
tlmgr: Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: Continuing anyway ...
Use of uninitialized value $r in split at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 3882.
tlmgr: Cannot find main repository, you have to tag one as main!
```

Should I merely ignore this xzdec problem? ... It seems as if the TeXstudio Ubuntu Software is incomplete, to be having so many issues; I think I installed 16.04 less than two weeks ago, and already installed all the updates when prompted.

It appears the answers to [Martin Drozdik's similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/371430/760090) may solve my problem. However, these answers are three years old: Is the information still correct?

**To be clear, my question is simply: How do I install packages for TeXstudio 2.10.8 in Ubuntu 16.04?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should install only these packages:

1. `texstudio` for TeXstudio 2.10.8
2. `texlive-latex-extra` for *placeins.sty* and *sectsty.sty*

with

```
sudo apt-get install texstudio texlive-latex-extra
```

---

One can always find needed packages by using search on https://packages.ubuntu.com using *Search the contents of packages* section - see [example](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=placeins.sty) for `placeins.sty`.

Comment: I think Ubuntu Software already installed that `texstudio` version, while your command installing `texlive-latex-extra` solved my problem. (`0 to upgrade, 8 to newly install, 0 to remove and 22 not to upgrade.`) Should I `sudo apt autoremove` apparently unneeded dependencies? Please see https://paste.ubuntu.com/26161853/ .

Comment: Removing unneeded dependencies will save space, so you could remove them.

Comment: This might be a good one-time answer but most of the people seeing that would want a broader answer on how could one install packages in general, not only the specific ones in the questions.

Comment: @borgr I completely agree. This got my resume to finally compile, but a more general solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Installing the `texlive-latex-extra` APT package fixed my issue when I was missing the `subfiles` and `todonotes` packages after reinstalling Ubuntu, cheers!